# Copy IntelliJ Module

Tags: intellij-idea, module, copy

How can I copy IntelliJ Module into new Project?
Currently when I add Module to Project Module is just referenced instead of making new Copy that I can change without impacting original Module.

Comment: Just copy the module's folder via File explorer